# How to get id in responseHeaders location?

Tags: karate

For my POST request, in responseHeaders I get `1 < location: /users/123`
I would like to print only the id > 123.
When I do `* print responseHeaders['location'][0]` in my feature file, I get `users/123`. How I can get only the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Karate question is it :P

Try this:

```
* def location = responseHeaders['location'][0]
* def userId = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
* print userId
```

That's right, all the power of JavaScript (or even Java via [Java interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java)) is available to you in Karate !

Comment: thanks it works. i'll try to use better js in my features