# Karate | String Split for CLI output

Tags: karate

I am trying to get the ip of the machine and pass to the endpoint with the below piece of code and getting the desired value in serviceId parameter.

'''* def output = karate.exec('ipconfig')

- def serviceId1 = output.split('IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :')[1]
- def serviceId = serviceId1.split(' ')[1]
- print serviceId'''

Is there any other simpler way i can implement this.

Comment: totally up to you. your knowledge of js / java and your creativity. another example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46359698/143475